# Disable table pagination in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I use [TablePagination](https://mui.com/api/table-pagination/#heading-props) component of Material-UI with React.

But this component doesn't have `disabled` prop.

I have a boolean `loading` value, which I want to use as a param to enable or disable arrows in the `TablePagination`.

How to achieve result like this?

I've tried to just pass `disabled` prop into `TablePagination`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not a single `disabled` switch, but you can set the `disabled` prop of the inner button components like this:

```
<TablePagination
  SelectProps={{
    disabled: isDisabled
  }}
  backIconButtonProps={
    isDisabled
      ? {
          disabled: isDisabled
        }
      : undefined
  }
  nextIconButtonProps={
    isDisabled
      ? {
          disabled: isDisabled
        }
      : undefined
  }
  {...}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]